# JavaScript - confirmation box. | Yes? > delete data from MySQL / No - do nothing

Tags: javascript, mysql

I don't have much experience with JavaScript. However I wanted to do a small thing with JavaScript and MySQL. And I could use some help.

I have a page in PHP which search for something and it's gives the results based on the search query.
For each result it adds 3 images, one which as a URL where you can view the content. Other where you can edit that content.

And the third one you can delete.
For that I wanted to do something nice.

Like, the user clicks the image, a confirmation dialog appears. In that box it asks if you sure you want to delete the data.
If yes, it would delete the data. where ID =

The ID is printed in the onclick action, inside the JavaScript function in the image using PHP `echo`.

If not, we would close the dialog and continue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so let's assume the following (forgive me for re-clarifying the question):

You have a number of rows of some form, with delete links, and you want to confirm that the user actually wants to delete it?

Let's assume the following HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>Some Item 1</td>
   <td><a href="?mode=delete&id=1" class="delete-link">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Some Item 2</td>
   <td><a href="?mode=delete&id=2" class="delete-link">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Some Item 3</td>
   <td><a href="?mode=delete&id=3" class="delete-link">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

So I'm assuming the same PHP script can run the delete, picking up on the mode parameter:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['mode'] == 'delete') {
       //Check if there is something in $_GET['id'].
       if($_GET['id']) {

          //Prevent SQL injection, just to be safe.
          $query = "DELETE FROM sometable WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";

          mysql_query($query);
       }
    }
```

I'm going to give two solutions to this on the JavaScript side - the first with an inline, slightly ugly solution, the second using jQuery (http://jquery.com/), and unobtrusive JavaScript.

Ok, so for the first, I would bind on the onclick event of each link.

```
<tr>
   <td>Some Item 3</td>
   <td><a href="?mode=delete&id=3" class="delete-link" onclick="checkDeleteItem();">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then create a JavaScript function:

```
//This will get called when the link is clicked.
function checkDeleteItem() {
   //show the confirmation box
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
}
```

As I said, I don't like that solution, because it is horribly obtrusive, and also not particularly robust.

Now, the jQuery solution:

```
//Do all this when the DOM is loaded
$(function() {
   //get all delete links (Note the class I gave them in the HTML)
   $("a.delete-link").click(function() {
       //Basically, if confirm is true (OK button is pressed), then
       //the click event is permitted to continue, and the link will
       //be followed - however, if the cancel is pressed, the click event will be stopped here.
       return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   });
});
```

I heartily recommend this solution over the previous one, since it is much more elegant and nice, and is generally best practice.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it.

Comment: *Please* try to avoid wiring up any data manipulation (especially deletion) to a GET request. GET is supposed to be safe and idempotent.

Comment: True - perhaps replacing the links with submit input elements is a wise move then (on a form with method=post).

Comment: I think the Javascript functions are bit redundant. You could just do onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');"

Comment: Tarski - His example though shows that he's wanting this for every single row in his returned results. Although the inline method you suggest is quick and simple (but "dirty") he'd end up with that code on every single result - i.e. bloat. Adding one event listener - either with jQuery as Peter's suggestion, or with pure JavaScript is the way to go in this case (IMHO!)

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the php part, but you can use JavaScript's `Confirm`:

```
var ok = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row');
//ok is true or false
```

You can bind a function to the click event on your delete buttons. Returning `false` will cause them to ignore the click.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a basic HTML form that will submit and do the deletion. Get the HTML right for this first - I would suggest each image has its own form with a hidden field for the ID value and the image uses an image button: `<input type="image" />`

Once you have this working you can add the JavaScript warning dialogue. You will need to replace the form's submit event with your own function that prevents the form from submitting (by returning false) and then show your dialogue. If the user clicks yes, then you'll need to trigger the forms `onsubmit()` event with JavaScript and if the user clicks no then just hide the dialogue.

Also, have a read about unobtrusive JavaScript - [DOM Scripting by Jeremy Keith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595335) is a fanastic book that will simply explain how to do this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button that deletes the row you want, then call the function below to confirm user if he wants to delete :

```
function confirmDelete()
{
  if (confirm('Do you want to delete ?'))
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```

call it like that :

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Record" onclick="confirmDelete()" />
```

Comment: Ach! return true/false when confirm already does the same thing? *Much* cleaner to just "return confirm('FooBar?')"